# Interpolating curve in spherical coordinates

Tags: matlab, 3d, interpolation, curve-fitting

I have points, which belongs to some non-parametric curve in 3D space. 
I need to work in spherical coordinates and interpolate given curve in given `azimuth` and `elevation` values.

Could you help me with algorithm of such interpolation?

**P.S.** I am not sure, that from my question idea of *1D curve drawn in 1D space* is clear. So, just in case code below create such, but parametric.

```
x=linspace(-2*pi,2*pi,10^3);
y=sin(x);
z=sinh(x);
```

## UPDATE:

Thanks @jodag for very good post about upsampling. `slerp` is perfect! Nevertheless, my problem is different, or I don't understand how to solve it using upsampling.
Let say I have my points defined as arrays (just some dummy data for demo):

```
x_given = rand(9, 1) - 0.5; 
y_given = rand(9, 1) - 0.5; 
z_given = rand(9, 1) - 0.5; 
x_given(end+1) = x_given(1); % should work for closed curves
y_given(end+1) = y_given(1); % should work for closed curves
z_given(end+1) = x_given(1); % should work for closed curves
```

I want to find all points (`x_i, y_i, z_i`) for given `elevation_q` and `azimuth_q`:

```
elevation_q = pi./4;
azimuth_q = pi./7;
[x_i, y_i ,z_i] = interpolateCurve(x_given, y_given, y_given, elevation_q, azimuth_q);
```

That what I really need. I understand, that we don't need to jump from Cartesian to Spherical coordinates forth and back. But even if I will substitute `x_given, y_given, y_given` to `elevation_given, azimuth_given, r_given`, I have no idea how to write `interpolateCurve()` function.

Comment: In spherical it will be still 3d. The problem that I am in trouble because of 3d. And because it is curve-not function. It may be deformated circle for example

Comment: You want to write the interpolator yourself? If you are using matlab, try `help interp3`.

Comment: @zlon I think I understand what your asking but I believe the question is ill posed. Your samples correspond to a curve in 3D space and you want to give the 1st and 2nd coordinate and determine what the 3rd coordinate is right? If your signal were a surface then great, we simply fit a surface then query it. However, since we are dealing with a curve we first have to determine if any points on the curve even take the given 2 coordinates. I haven't thought up a way to solve this that doesn't rely on lots of heuristics.

Comment: @jodag You are absolutely right. It is the problem. If it is easier, than we may assume that it is always cycle with (0,0,0) at the middle, then I may rotate it to have point with any given elevation for example. I also think, that I may reformulate question as "how to interpolate intersection of 3D curve and line" will it helps?

Comment: I'm beginning to think this may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of linear interpolation of a curve in a higher dimensional space. Notice that I introduce a parameterization variable `t` corresponding to the indices of the points.

```
function [xq,yq,zq] = interp_sph(x,y,z,upsample)
    [az,el,r] = cart2sph(x,y,z);
    t = 1:numel(x);
    tq = 1:(1/upsample):numel(x);
    azq = interp1(t,az,tq);
    elq = interp1(t,el,tq);
    rq = interp1(t,r,tq);
    [xq,yq,zq] = sph2cart(azq,elq,rq);
end
```

It's not clear from the question if this is what you are actually looking for. There are definitely issues with direct interpolation in spherical coordinates. For example, if two points are near each other but one has azimuth=-179 degrees and the other has azimuth=179 then rather than taking the shortest 2 degree path, the interpolation will produce samples spanning [-179,179]. What you may be interested is [slerp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) which gives nicer interpolation results.

I wrote the following slerp example to demonstrate. Note that slerp requires that `1/sin(theta)` is defined where `theta` is the angle between two points in the function. If `theta == pi` then we have a problem and slerp won't work so be careful if your data is close to the origin.

```
function [xq,yq,zq] = interp_slerp(x,y,z,upsample)
    r = sqrt(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2);
    vq = zeros(3,(upsample-1)*(numel(x)-1)+1);
    for idx = 1:numel(x)-1
        t = 0:1;
        tq = linspace(0,1,upsample);
        % compute interpolated direction
        dq = slerp([x(idx),y(idx),z(idx)],[x(idx+1),y(idx+1),z(idx+1)],tq);
        % linearly interpolate radius
        rq = interp1(t,r(idx:(idx+1)),tq);
        % get interpolated path
        idxq = (idx-1)*upsample + 1;
        vq(:,idxq:(idxq+(upsample-1))) = bsxfun(@times,rq,dq);
    end
    xq = vq(1,:);
    yq = vq(2,:);
    zq = vq(3,:);
end

function pq = slerp(p0,p1,t)
    p0 = p0(:) / norm(p0);
    p1 = p1(:) / norm(p1);
    theta = acos( dot(p0,p1) );
    if(0==theta)
        pq = a;
    elseif(pi==theta)
        error('Angle between points cannot be exactly pi.');
    else
        pq = bsxfun(@times,(sin((1.0-t)*theta)/sin(theta)),p0) + bsxfun(@times,(sin(t*theta)/sin(theta)),p1);
    end
end
```

To demonstrate the problem with `interp_sph` consider the following example.

```
% create test path
az = pi+sin(linspace(pi/2,3*pi/2,10));
el = cos(linspace(-pi,pi,10));
r = 1 + 1/5*sin(6*az).*sin(5*el);
[x,y,z] = sph2cart(az,el,r);

% test both spherical interpolation and slerp
upsample = 20;
[xq_sph,yq_sph,zq_sph] = interp_sph(x,y,z,upsample);
[xq_slerp,yq_slerp,zq_slerp] = interp_slerp(x,y,z,upsample);

% plot results
plot3(x,y,z,'LineWidth',2); hold on;
plot3(xq_sph,yq_sph,zq_sph,'LineWidth',2);
plot3(xq_slerp,yq_slerp,zq_slerp,'LineWidth',2);
axis('vis3d');
axis([-1,1,-1,1,-1,1]);
grid('on');
legend('Cartisian', 'Spherical', 'SLERP');
```

This produces the plot below. Notice that spherical interpolation takes the long way around when azimuth goes from positive to negative, but slerp takes the expected route.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a perfect answer. `slerp` is awesome - I've never heard. Nevertheless, I need interpolation, but not upsampling. I've update my question. Could You be so kind to have a look?